# Is there a way to use const using traditional function declaration

Tags: javascript, function

I am new to JS and still a newbie.
So I am learning new ways of using functions in JS like the arrow fucntions.
const func= () => {}

We can use var and const in arrow functions
Is there any way to use it the traditional function declaration methods like -

function func() {
}

Comment: Yes. Do you have a particular example in mind?

Comment: You're mixing function declaration and function expression. Arrow functions are always function expressions, they can't have a name and they can't be declared. You can make a "traditional" function expression and assign it to a variable as well, like `const func = function () {};`, or copy a refrence to a declared function: `function func () {}; const func2 = func;`.

Answer (score 0):

Among dozens of different ways of declaring a function the following 2 are the most commonly used (and favored by the JS community:

> 1. Arrow Function: `const Foo = () => {}`
> 2. Regular Function: `function () {}`

And that is why you almost always see the above formats throughout the not only the beginning, but also the rest of your programming career!
But that does not, necessarily, mean you cannot use some other alternatives i.e. "const/var in traditional way of declaring"

One good example can be a named function expression:

```
const count = function(array) { // Function expression
  return // something;
}
```

For a better understanding, I would suggest checking out the following blog post: [6 Ways to Declare JS Functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/)